# How to close IE Popup ActiveX window in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, activex

I am trying to close a Active X window in IE Browser with Selenium Java. I tried

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

This driver close method popping up with another confirmation window. Manually I can close this window by X button or Alt+F4. I did some research and couple of threads saying that Selenium can't handle ActiveX windows.

In that case Can I use java script with selenium to close window? Or Can I send Alt+F4 command using Selenium? I don't care about the window content, I just want to close the window.

Update: Screenshot attached below per request. The active x window I am referring to here is titled as "xxx Image Viewer -- Webpage Dialog". I clicked on help ? button to get the more details of the window and it is displayed in "xxxx Active-X"

).[image]

Comment: Down voters please consider adding the reason of your vote

Comment: Can you attach an image on how your **ActiveX window** looks like? I presume it can be handled by **Robot class**, but I need to be sure if its even required or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending **"Alt+F4"** keys using **Robot class** of **"java.awt package"** and **KeyEvent class** of **"java.awt.event package"** as below, in order to close the ActiveX window **(Assuming the focus is on the ActiveX window, when it pops up)**:

```
Thread.sleep(3000);// Some sleep time in order to detect the presence of Active X window

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
```

Comment: Subh, As per you said the Alt+F4 key combinations are sending, but it is not closing the window.

Comment: @KodS: When manually navigating, do you have to click on the pop-up window(for focus) and then use ALT+F4 to close it, or does only using ALT+F4 directly closes the pop up ?

Comment: It is already focused on current window, I used method to get Title of page and confirmed it is current window.

Comment: By current window, you mean the popped up window,right?